# Installing npm packages, after recieving the node modules folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, math, npm, project

My name is Jaffer Syed and I am wondering how to install npm packages into my code. 
I am trying to install num2fraction https://www.npmjs.com/package/num2fraction but in you npm package video you didnt go into how to install npm packages and how to actually make it work in the javascript. I added the command for the package in the command line but it doesn't seem to work for some reason and when I find the error it keeps saying that the require is not defined.

my js looks like this for trying to implement the num2fraction

```
    var n2f = require('num2fraction')

     console.log(n2f(2.555))
```

thank you

Comment: Make sure you are using node.js and not trying to run this file in the browser

Comment: do you have a package.json file? can you post it here?

Comment: which framework you are using ?

Comment: {
  "name": "calculateproject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "JAFFER SYED",
  "license": "MIT",
  "keywords": [],
  "description": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "loadash": "^1.0.0",
    "num2fraction": "^1.2.2"
  }
}

Comment: try `npm install` in your terminal (while in the file directory)

Answer (score 0):

here is a sample script for how I did what you're trying:

```
mkdir foo
cd foo
npm init
```

just accept all the default options here

```
npm install -s num2fraction
```

put your exact contents above into a file called foo.js in this directory and save

```
node foo.js
```

should output 511/200